# How to use result of server method within client side collection hook?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to set up some server and client side before.insert and before.update hooks using matb33:collection-hooks and I need the document to be enhanced with the result of a server side method.

I cannot do it purely on the client due to lack of certain libraries on the client.

I cannot do it purely on the server because I need the result immediately without which the UI flickers and jumps around too much.

The problem is, the server side method being called asynchronously on the client thus leaving me with undefined.

Is there a clean way to run a blocking function that I can use within a client side before.insert / before.update hook to get some result from the server?

EDIT:
I *must* have access to the result of a server side function (or method) before even continuing with the client stub. Therefore, my question boils down to this:

How can I create a blocking function on the client that waits for the result of a server side function.

I cannot mock or simulate a temporary value on the client. I do not need/want latency compensation. Blocking is what I need and want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same functionality as you were using on the client side, however add a tag to the collection object say `readyForServer : false`. After the client has performed the desired actions on the object, set the `readyForServer : true` and then observe the change on the server looking specifically for that `readyForServer === true` attribute. Below is an example of how the server code would look. I assume that you already have a working client side hook:

```
// Watch For File Additions
Files.find().observeChanges({
  added : function (id, fields) {
     // Don't want to watch added
  },
  changed : function (id, fields) {
    if (fields.readerForServer) {
      // Complete server side actions

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: My requirement is for a package I'm developing and it needs to be transparent on the client and should not require code modification and should be selective. A monkeypatch pattern like this on the server requires either the dev or the package code to set up observers regardless of that. But thanks for the idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stub. Because there is latency with the server, if you want to avoid the flickering you can add 'virtual' fields temporarily while the result of the server is waiting.

All you need to do is create a matching method for a `Meteor.call` on the client side. This method will run in a simulation mode for the UI's sake only.

//Client side

```
Meteor.call("insert_my_doc", { value: '2'});

Meteor.methods({
    insert_my_doc: function(doc) {
        doc.added_value = 'this is an added value';
        MyCollectionWithHooks.insert(doc);
    }
});
```

//Server side

```
Meteor.methods({
    insert_my_doc: function(doc) {
        MyCollectionWithHooks.insert(doc);
    }
});

MyCollection.before.insert(function(doc) {
    doc.added_value = 'something';
});
```

Here added value would be '2' instead of nothing, then correct itself to 'something'. Of course you could make it be anything else.

If you are more specific with the changes you want to do to the document I could modify the answer a bit with your needs. But it would be along the lines of something like this as you would have to have something on the client give a fakeish temporary value while the server responds (which wont be instantly).

With your last question, it is not possible in any way (without ES6 features which aren't fully released yet and not available on everyones browsers) to run a blocking method.

If you feel this is okay for your need you can use a generator for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely need the server result on the client before I proceed with doc creation. And it is not a result that I can substitute or mock on the client. I have to wait for that result before insertion goes on, even if it is in a stub.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy you have to expect some UI simulation. With a blocking solution, if you decide to use generators, basically freezes up the UI which is a bit worse. Perhaps you can put in a loading screen while the method is waiting to complete?

Comment: I'm ok with a blocking UI. In fact, that's exactly what I want as I explained.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I've provided something you can do for this case, you can use generators. The browser will need ES6 enabled i'm afraid. There isn't a way around this due to the restrictions on client side javascript.

Comment: Thanks Akshat, my gut feeling tells me the same unfortunately I am not familiar with ES6 concepts yet. If you can edit your answer with a basic example of a "blocking async" call to a server-side meteor method, I'll go ahead and mark this one as the accepted answer for the sake of future reference.